# Understanding Vitali's convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am facing difficulty in understanding Vitali's convergence theorem in the unbounded setting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem

Basically, the above link says, if given for example, $X=\mathbb{R}^N$, $f_n\in L^p(X)$, $1<p<\infty$. Then to prove $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p(X)$, it is enough to prove the following three parts:

1. $f_n\to f$ pointiwse in $X$.
2. $f_n$ is uniformly absolutely continuous (UAC). I think, by UAC, we mean that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ such that for every $A\subset X$ with $|A|<\delta_{\epsilon}$, one has
   $$
   \sup_{n\geq 1}\int_{A}|f_n|\,dx<\epsilon.
   $$
3. For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $X_{\epsilon}\subset X$ such that $|X_{\epsilon}|<\infty$ and $$
   \sup_{n\geq 1}\int_{X\setminus X_{\epsilon}}|f_n|^p\,dx<\epsilon.
   $$

Now, I was trying to get the same claim $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p(X)$, if (1) and (3) above holds, but (2) is replaced by the (4) as follows:

Before mentioning (4), I mention the idea behind (4), which is split $\int_X |f_n|=\int_{X\setminus X_\epsilon}|f_n|+\int_{X_\epsilon}|f_n|$ and try to prove both these integrals small separately. Already for a fixed $\epsilon>0$, by (2) we know the first integral is small. Now to prove the second integral $\int_{X_\epsilon}|f_n|$ small, suppose we have
(4) for every $A\subset X_\epsilon$ such that $|A|$ small imply
$$
\sup_{n\geq 1}\int_{A}|f_n|^p\,dx
$$
small. Then, by Vitali's theorem for bounded sets, we can say that
$$
\sup_{n\geq 1}\int_{X_\epsilon}|f_n|^p\,dx
$$
is small.

Therefore, (4) replaces the assumption (2) in Vitali's theorem to get the  convergence $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p(X)$.

Still, it is unclear if I am correct. Can someone please have a look and confirm it? Thanks.